# Button.DialogResult, Form.ShowDialog and async event handlers out of -expected- order execution

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I gonna try to be brief. Two Forms:

Form1 (button1, textBox1)

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Form2 fr2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fr2.textBox1 = textBox1;
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        if (fr2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        textBox1.AppendText("Form1" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

---

Form2 (button1 with **button1.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK**)

---

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public TextBox textBox1;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("Form2 A" + Environment.NewLine);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        textBox1.AppendText("Form2 B" + Environment.NewLine);
        Hide();
    }
}
```

---

- Run
- Click on Form1.Button1
- Click on Form2.Button1

WHY Textbox.Text ==

```
@"Form2 A
Form1
Form2 B
";
```

instead of

```
@"Form2 A
Form2 B
Form1
"?
```

WHY the form "returns" to the caller without even finishing the event handler and finish later?

Is this a documented behaviour or a bug?

Update:

Apparently the original winform's form event handing code wasn't updated to account for an async event handler in case button.DialogResult is preset, it's just treated as a "fire and forget" async method call. I have to study some more to see what happens in case an exception is thrown. It seems that is "fired and forgotten" too by the async machinery (no `Task` to save it for later)?! It is a very different behaviour from the serial case and it's not documented anywhere. Spot on comment about `await`, Hans Passant!

Comment: I assume the code in Form1 is suppose to add "Form1 A" and not just "Form1"?

Comment: Its because of the await, the keyword that launched a million bugs.  Set the button's DialogResult property back to None so your code stays in control over the dialog lifetime.   Don't use Hide(), that cancels the dialog, use this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

Comment: @JackT.Spades Yes. you are right. To cut and paste and edit after is not a not  good way for avoiding mistakes ;-) Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, as you wait asynchronously for the `Task.Delay` task to finish. While that is being done, the method returns to its caller, and this is by design. Take this example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   method();
   textBox1.Text += "C";
}

async void method()
{
   textBox1.Text += "A";
   await Task.Delay(1000);
   textBox1.Text += "B";
}
```

This is pretty much the same situation, the text of the TextBox will be `ACB` after pressing button1, as the method `method()` returns to its caller when `await Task.Delay(1000);` is called.

To get the desired output, do it as Hans Passant suggested in the comments: Set the `DialogResult` property of the button to `None`, so that the method does not return to the `Form1`. Then, whenever you wish to hand control over to `Form1` again, simply call `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` in the method on runtime, which will have the same effect.